# PHP скрипт закачки файла, на сервер

Tags: php

используя данный скрипт для закачки файла на сервер (крон запускает его), файл закачивается на сервер, но пустым, подскажите в чем может быть проблема? (права 777 везде)

Изначально его вес 3,61 МБ, после закачки 0 МБ

```
<?php
exec ('wget -O list.txt -x http://www.mydomain.net/test/list.txt');
exec ('mv list.txt ./xml/');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Открывать файлы надо не exec, а file_get_contents()
Если использовать exec, то я, как злоумышленник, смогу найти способ загружать файл PHP, на ваш сервер даже в виде .xml и исполнять его. А я могу удалить полностью все исходники, украсть базу данных, да все что угодно через свои исходники